# SQL: Select like column from two tables

Tags: sql

I have a database with two tables (`Table1` and `Table2`). They both have a common column `[ColumnA]` which is an `nvarchar`.

How can I select this column from both tables and return it as a single column in my result set?

So I'm looking for something like:

```
ColumnA in Table1:
a
b
c

ColumnA in Table2:
d
e
f

Result set should be:
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM Table1 UNION Select ColumnB FROM Table2 ORDER BY 1
```

Also, if you know the contents of Table1 and Table2 will **NEVER** overlap, you can use UNION ALL in place of UNION instead.  Saves a little bit of resources that way.

-- Kevin Fairchild

Comment: You can do ORDER BY 1 in your first query to avoid the need for the subquery when ordering.

Comment: AFAIK, SQL Server in particular would automatically order by the column selected even without the explicit ORDER BY. But that is only true for UNION cases, and not for UNION ALL ones. And ORDER BY improves readibility where ordering is intended by design.

Answer (score 3):

Do you care if you get dups or not?

UNION will be slower than UNION ALL because UNION  will filter out dups

Answer (score 1):

Use the [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operator:

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ColumnA FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 1):

The union answer is *almost* correct, depending on overlapping values:

```
SELECT distinct ColumnA FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT distinct ColumnA FROM Table2
```

If 'd' appeared in Table1 or 'c' appeared in Table2 you would have multiple rows with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union select:

```
Select columnA from table1 union select columnA from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.d, Table2.e, Table2.f 
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.a = Table2.a
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Edit: It appears I did.

Comment: My initial read of the question was the same as yours, JesDaw. Original poster, it would have been a little clearer to explain that "a, b, c", etc, were the *values* in ColumnA, especially since you used the letter a for both a column and a value. Just nitpicking, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's:

```
SELECT columna FROM table1 UNION SELECT columnb FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle (at least) there is UNION and UNION ALL, UNION ALL will return all results from both sets even if there are duplicates, where as UNION will return the distinct results from both sets.