# SQL: Select like column from two tables and give constraint by Id

Tags: sql

I have development question from this link [SQL: Select like column from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181/sql-select-like-column-from-two-tables)

ColumnA in Table1:

```
a
b
c
```

ColumnA in Table2:

```
d
e
f
```

Result set should be:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

then in that table have complaintId, I want filter by complaintId, but error in where clause.
this is my sql looks alike

```
SELECT firstName, message, date
FROM replyComplaintUsers rcu
  JOIN users u ON rcu.userId = u.userId
UNION
SELECT firstName, message, date
FROM replyComplaintControls rcc
  JOIN controls c ON rcc.controlId = c.controlId
WHERE rcu.complaintId = $complaintId and rcc.complaintId = $complaintId
ORDER BY date DESC
```

can somebody tell me what is wrong?

this value i get when I use this sql
Unknown column 'rcu.complaintId' in 'where clause'
thanks

Comment: The WHERE clause applies to the second SELECT only.

Comment: where is the complaintId  field in your select clause ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query the `WHERE` clause applies to the `UNION`'s second `SELECT` only. Do a derived table:

```
select firstName, message, date, complaintId 
from
(
SELECT firstName, message, date, complaintId 
FROM replyComplaintUsers rcu
  JOIN users u ON rcu.userId = u.userId
UNION
SELECT firstName, message, date, complaintId 
FROM replyComplaintControls rcc
  JOIN controls c ON rcc.controlId = c.controlId
) as t
WHERE t.complaintId = $complaintId
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Note 1: DATE is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, you may need to specify `"DATE"`.

Note 2: I don't know the data, but often `UNION ALL` is what people want when they do `UNION`. (I.e. don't try to remove duplicated rows.) Gives better performance!

Comment: thank you @jarlh
i should put "WHERE" on two tables
"SELECT firstName, message, date FROM replyComplaintUsers rcu JOIN users u ON rcu.userId = u.userId WHERE rcu.complaintId = $complaintId UNION SELECT firstName, message, date FROM replyComplaintControls rcc JOIN controls c ON rcc.controlId = c.controlId WHERE rcc.complaintId = $complaintId ORDER BY date DESC "
it works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
SELECT firstName, message, date 
FROM replyComplaintUsers rcu
  JOIN users u ON rcu.userId = u.userId
  where rcu.complaintId = $complaintId
UNION
SELECT firstName, message, date
FROM replyComplaintControls rcc
  JOIN controls c ON rcc.controlId = c.controlId
WHERE   rcc.complaintId = $complaintId) DV_Table
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: @Faisal but you didnt pressed the up button..:)

Comment: my reputation still under 15 sorry :)
i will upvote later @anwaar_hell

Comment: please upvote my question and I can upvote your answer @anwaar_hell